# Return pointer of file/folder struct in function

Tags: c, arrays, winapi, pointers, struct

I'm trying to create a function that returns an array of pointers to structs but I get weird behavior when returning the array. This is the struct:

```
struct DLLs{
    char* FolderName = (char*)(malloc(sizeof(char*)*LongExtFileName));
    char* CppFileName = (char*)(malloc(sizeof(char*)*LongExtFileName));
};
```

And this is my function. This function opens a given path folder and returns it's SubFolders contained in it. Example: "C:\" will return a array of X size, where array[0]->FolderName = "AMD", array[1] = "A_files"... Etc. according to any computer and folder contained in C:*.

```
DLLs** GetFiles(char* DirPath, char* Extension){

    DLLs* arr[1]; //NULL struct in case there are wrong folders in given path
    arr[0] = (DLLs*)malloc(sizeof(DLLs*)*16);
    arr[0]->FolderName = "NULL";
    arr[0]->CppFileName = "NULL";

    char* path = (char*)(malloc(sizeof(char*)*LongExtFileName));
    path[0] = 0;

    strcat(path, DirPath);
    strcat(path, Extension); //This modifies the given path to search with WINAPI function
                             //path is changed to search files by: path\Extension, where Extension is a given extensión as \.cpp -> C:\*.cpp
                             //If extensions given by user is "\\*" it will search folders

    int NumFiles; //Number of folders found
    void* rootPath;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FileInformation;


    if ((rootPath = FindFirstFile((path), &FileInformation)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)       
        return arr; //Wrong folder path given

    else NumFiles = 0;

    do {
        if(FileInformation.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY){
            NumFiles++;
        }

    } while (FindNextFile(rootPath, &FileInformation));

    FindClose(rootPath);

    if(!(NumFiles-2)) return arr; //If not folders found, skipping "." and ".." folders, return null struct.

    DLLs* array[NumFiles - 2]; //Create array of pointers of structs of number of found folders
    int i = -1;

    rootPath = FindFirstFile(path, &FileInformation);
    FindNextFile(rootPath, &FileInformation);
    FindNextFile(rootPath, &FileInformation); //Skip "." and ".." folders

    do {
        if(FileInformation.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY){
            array[i] = (DLLs*)malloc(sizeof(DLLs*)*256); //Allocate struct memory
            array[i]->FolderName = FileInformation.cFileName;
            printf("%s\n", array[i]->FolderName);
                    //When printing names in this process, it shows folders names correctly in console.

    }

    } while (++i, FindNextFile(rootPath, &FileInformation));

    FindClose(rootPath);

    //Weird behavior starts here:
    printf("\n\nFolders Saved:\n\n");
    for(i = 0; i<NumFiles-2; i++)
    printf("%s\n", array[i]->FolderName);  

    return array;   
};
```

When I print the struct information saved at the time a folder is found, it prints it fine, when the folder finding cycle ends and I make a for to show the struct array information one by one, the array is a weird mess, sometimes crashes or sometimes it just prints the first folder name correctly and the rest with weird symbols.

Comment: This isn't valid C. Please post code that actually compiles.

Comment: @Lundin Why it is not valid C? Give an explanation

Comment: I read 2 lines of code then found some nonsense syntax, then I stopped reading, as your compiler would have told you it is nonsense too. At a closer look, the rest of the code looks like valid C. However, you really need to pick up a coding and indention style which is readable and consistent, if you wish that others read/maintain your code.

Comment: I find nonsene in your comment lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not permitted to have `=` in a struct definition. I don't know what you were trying to do anyway. A struct definition looks like:

```
struct DLLs
{
    char *FolderName;
    char *CppFileName;
};
```

Later on you can declare variables of this type and make that variable's pointers point somewhere.

---

This is hopeless:

```
DLLs* array[NumFiles - 2];
// ...
return array;
```

because you are returning a pointer to a local variable. `array` is destroyed when the function returns. To make `array` persist longer than the function it is declared in, you must either make it `static`, or use dynamic allocation.

Even if you fix this, another bug is:

```
array[i]->FolderName = FileInformation.cFileName;
```

The `FileInformation` structure is local to the function too, so once the function exits, that pointer will be pointing to invalid memory.

To fix this you could use dynamic allocation again, although you must be consistent and dynamically allocate all FolderNames so that you can `free` them later.

It is really important that you think about where things are in memory, how long they will be allocated for, and where pointers are pointing. It may help to draw a *memory map* on a piece of paoer so you can see where the variables are and what's pointing at what.

Answer (score 2):

the way you declare variable 'array', it is created on the stack and is not valid outside your function. You'll have to use malloc to allocate space for 'array' if you want to use it outside of this function.